# MySQL - Rows with specific string into Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to get 4 results that would normally return in 4 rows to be returned in just 2 rows.

I have this query:

```
SELECT meta_key, meta_value, t.post_date_gmt FROM (SELECT * 
FROM dr_posts
JOIN dr_postmeta ON post_id = ID
WHERE post_author = 2
AND post_type ='donation') AS t WHERE meta_key = '_donation_amount' OR meta_key= '_anonymous_donation'
```

Which returns:

```
=======================================================
|       meta-key       |  meta-value  | post_date_gmt |
=======================================================
| _anonymous_donation  |       0      |   2015-03-01  |
|   _donation_amount   |       10     |   2015-03-01  |
| _anonymous_donation  |       0      |   2015-03-02  |
|   _donation_amount   |       15     |   2015-03-02  |
_______________________________________________________
```

What I really want (column names isn't important - just the result):

```
=============================================================
| _anonymous_donation  |  _donation_amount  | post_date_gmt |
=============================================================
|           0          |         10         |   2015-03-01  |
|           0          |         15         |   2015-03-02  |
_____________________________________________________________
```

How to do this? I read that I need to use `PIVOT` but I'm unsure if this is what I actually need.

Comment: Sample table data would make it all clearer.

Comment: @jarlh, what kind of sample data do you want?

Comment: Try providing some sample data in http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: For example the data you had when running your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query should do what you want:

```
select 
    max(case when meta_key =  '_anonymous_donation' then meta_value end) as '_anonymous_donation',
    max(case when meta_key =  '_donation_amount' then meta_value end) as '_donation_amount',
    post_date_gmt
from (SELECT * 
    FROM dr_posts
    JOIN dr_postmeta ON post_id = ID
    WHERE post_author = 2
    AND post_type ='donation'
    ) AS t
WHERE meta_key = '_donation_amount' OR meta_key= '_anonymous_donation'
group by post_date_gmt
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it may helps

```
select min(meta-value) as  _anonymous_donation,
       max(meta-value) as _donation_amount,
       post_date_gmt  
from table
group by post_date_gmt
```